# Count non zero numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, excel-2019

I have a string in one cell 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,2,5,4,0,5,4,7,6,7,8,0,8,9,8,8,10,11,0,9,10,9,8,10,9,0,15,18,17,16,17,16,0,17,16,17,16,15,14,0,12,11,10,9,10,9,0,7,8,7,6,5

In this I want to count all non zero characters but when I'm using Len and substitute function to do the same, I'm not getting 50.

I need a formula which will not count the zero, space, comma and will count 1 digit numbers as 1, 2 digit numbers as 1 and so on.

Comment: How about `TEXTSPLIT` to break them into an array?

Comment: I place the string in `A1` and then count the non-zeroes `SUM(N(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,,",")<>0))` and got 50

Comment: Looks like Textsplit is not supported in my Excel version (2019)

Comment: @silbia use `FILTERXML()` --> `=SUMPRODUCT(N(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")<>0))`

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L5</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(
  FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(L3,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")<>0)
  )
```

---

To know more on <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd> please take a look on this reference created by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir. A complete **encyclopedia** on the above function and its usages.

**[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)**

---

**Caveat:** Since you are using **`Excel 2019`** make sure to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the **edit mode**.

---

However, with **`MS365`** I would have used <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> as mentioned above by **[Rosetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5332500/rosetta)** wrapped within a <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> and <kbd>N( )</kbd> to coerce the <kbd>BOOLEANS</kbd> to `1` and `0`s respectively.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L5</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(L3,",")<>"0"))
```

---

Or, More cleaner and less verbose way as mentioned in comments by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L5</kbd>

```
=ROWS(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(L3,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[.!=0]"))
```

---

Comment: Nice use of `FILTERXML()`. You can also directly filter the nodes using xpath: `=ROWS(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(L3,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[.!=0]"))`

Comment: Alright @JvdV Sir, understood thank you very much as always.

Answer (score 3):

For Excel -2019, I believe that the following might work:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",0",))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",0",),",",))
```

Comment: More simpler way, sir your presence of mind is always great.

Comment: Some of the stuff around I see makes nice use of new dynamic functions though.

Comment: Absolutely sir agreed!

Comment: Here's a slightly obscure variant which saves one substitution =LEN(","&A1)/2+LEN(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",0",))/2-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",))

Comment: @TomSharpe thanks. could just be good enough for OP here. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

### Count Non-Zeros in Delimited String

**Single Cell**

```
=LET(data,A1,
    d,--TEXTSPLIT(data,,","),
    f,FILTER(d,ISNUMBER(d)),
COUNT(FILTER(f,f<>0)))
```

**Range**

```
=LET(data,A1:C4,
MAP(data,LAMBDA(r,LET(
    d,--TEXTSPLIT(r,,","),
    f,FILTER(d,ISNUMBER(d)),
COUNT(FILTER(f,f<>0))))))
```

**Variables**

```
d - split and converted to numbers (in a column)
f - only numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, see picture for details:

```
=LET(
    t, C3,
    r, C1,
    clean, REDUCE(
        t,
        MID(r, SEQUENCE(LEN(r)), 1),
        LAMBDA(u,v, TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(u, v, " ")))
    ),
    COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(clean, " "))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use this formula for count non-zero number in cell.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)<>","), --(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)<>"0"))`

It works for me I hope you too. if doesn't work let me know your software version.

Comment: The string is in one cell, so why do you have a range?

Comment: okay so you can use below

=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)<>","), --(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)<>"0"))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).